# NextCord.py Doesn't Respond

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

*edit: I tried to make it ctx.send. it didnt work.

I am a newbie Python developer. I have been using Discord.py for a while.
I heard about NextCord and decided to use it.

***Also: I made sure the intents are set up correctly. The code doesn't give me an error. It just doesn't respond!***

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from termcolor import colored
import os
os.system('color')

logo = """
█┼┼ ███ ███- ███ ███ ███ ██▄
█┼┼ █▄┼ █┼█- █┼┼ █┼█ █▄┼ █┼█
█▄█ █▄▄ █▄█- ███ █▄█ █┼█ ███
"""

print(colored(logo, "green"))
print(colored("Lam Bot coded by LeoDev only!", "green"))

TOKEN = 'token'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(colored("Bot Ready!","green"))

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

When I send "$ping" in the server I put the bot in, it simply doesn't respond. No errors. ***Just nothing!***

Comment: I think it’s ctx.send not reply, there is not application context to reply

Comment: I tried that too! @FishballNooodles

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
```

To

```py
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="$",intents=intents)
```